# referencing a key/value in django-templates after applying a filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

say I have the following list that I provide to a django template

```
stuff= [ { 'a':2 , 'b':4 } , { 'a',7} ]
```

I want to access the 'a' attribute of the first element. I can't quite get the syntax right.

```
{{stuff|first}}
```

gives me the first element, but

```
{{stuff|first.a}}
```

is a dead end ( and weird )

and I can't seem to find a attribute filter. Short of writing one myself, is there template language syntax for what I want to do ?

```
stuff[0].a is no go as well
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is off the top of my head, but I think it is

```
{{ stuff.0.a }}
```